# The power shell command do not work in Yaml pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am in process of converting my release pipeline to a Yaml pipeline. The task is to call a Power Shell script which is generating some data in a notebook in my SharePoint site. I am able to do it successfully in my release pipeline but in my Yaml Pipeline while calling PowerShell File it is giving me error like

*"The '<' operator is reserved for future use." and "The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double  quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string."*

I see that this is an issue with PowerShell version but then how it is working with my classic release pipeline. How can I fix this for yaml pipeline??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is due is because of the Powershell version.
I don't know what are you trying to  do with the operator, but an example workaround can be:

```
.\sample.exe < test.full | tee test.log
```

```
Get-Content test.full | .\sample.exe | tee test.log
```

And regarding the & operator, if you are using it to call another script, you don't need to use the it to call a script from another script.  Simply call it by full path name, or .\scriptname.ps1 if it's in the current directory.

If you can't resolve your problem, please show the original powershell script.

Comment: i don't know what I did but I just copied the script from my release pipeline to my yaml pipeline and it worked. previously I was writing new scripts by creating a new file. is there anywhere in YAML , i might have changed the version??

Comment: Is hard to know without see the pipelines and the scripts and even the agents pools. If you are running the pipelines with hosted agents, then the last version of powershell is used. But if you are using self hosted agents, may be not.

Please if the answer is helpful for you, you can accept the answer which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-) –